# c # devexpress empty column error, application crash when value returned empty

Tags: c#, devexpress

I get the data with c # devexpress gridview and print it on the screen. But when I try to edit a row, if the row is "null", it returns the following error message.

How can I fix this?

[image: error]

```
  try
        {
            txtCustomerGender.Text = gridViewHastaListesi.GetRowCellValue(gridViewHastaListesi.FocusedRowHandle, "CustomerGender").ToString();
            txtCustomerPhone.Text = gridViewHastaListesi.GetRowCellValue(gridViewHastaListesi.FocusedRowHandle, gridViewHastaListesi.Columns["CustomerPhone"]).ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ToString() method on a null value will throw a null reference exception. You should first see if the value of the column is null before you attempt to convert it to a string.

Comment: Hello Brendon, would you mind to look at that If you got opinion on it Will be appreciated :)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643711/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-idatalayer-with-same-sqlconnection-devexpress-xpo

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the value is null before use ToString().

```
txtCustomerPhone.Text = gridViewHastaListesi.GetRowCellValue(gridViewHastaListesi.FocusedRowHandle, gridViewHastaListesi.Columns["CustomerPhone"])!=null ? gridViewHastaListesi.GetRowCellValue(gridViewHastaListesi.FocusedRowHandle, gridViewHastaListesi.Columns["CustomerPhone"]).ToString():"";
```